# Best way to share class attributes among processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Let's say that I have a lot of instances of a class. This class has a `run` function, which I am running through a Process in order to spread out work over multiple cores. The class also has an attribute `c` that I am accessing in the `run` function. The problem is, when I change one of the instance's `c`, it is not seen as updated in the output of the `run` function.

Demonstration:

```
import multiprocessing
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 0
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print self.c
test1 = Test()
p = Process(target = test1.run, args=())
p.start()
test1.c = 5
```

Expected output:

```
5
5
5
5
```

Actual output:

```
0
0
0
0
```

What's the best way to make sure that the variable is synced correctly among processes? (My actual code is a lot more complex - including many more objects, classes, and variables)

Comment: Sharing state using `multiprocessing` is non-trivial

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264699/shared-state-in-python-multiprocessing-processes). But think about it, you are working with multiple *processes*. The variables are never "synced". You have to [implement that yourself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). As the docs say, though, you want to avoid sharing state as much as possible.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think **share memory** in multiprocessing is a better way for OP, not the dup. For instance, [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see. The reason I was looking into `multiprocessing` was to utilize more CPU cores - the `threading` library is unable to do this. Is there another library similar to `threading` that is able to utilize multiple CPU cores?

Comment: Nope. You can use `threading` in a different Python implementation that lacks a GIL, though. E.g. Jython, IronPython...

Comment: @frankyjuang that is *linked to in the accepted answer of the dupe*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Are Jython and IronPython drop-in replacements for CPython? That is, do they require any modification of Python code?

Comment: @acer the availability of libraries might be an issue. But for just plain Python, they should work. Although, it seems they might only support up to Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) provides an API for easily spawning subprocesses, not threads. This isn't just semantics; the reason you aren't getting your expected results is that separate processes do not share memory spaces (where threads do).

[Here](https://repl.it/JLyH) is a quick example to demonstrate. The thread is the one that prints the 5, whereas the subprocess prints the 0.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html) is the documentation for the threading library, which I believe is what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there any way to use the threading library and spread the processing over multiple cores? One of the reasons I was leaning towards multiprocessing was that it played well with multi-core systems.

Comment: As mentioned in some of the comments on the question, I think any interpreter that does not implement a [global interpreter lock](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) should let threads and multi-core CPUs to play nice together. Also see [the wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)