# python mutable objet through a process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mutable

I'd like to get list value modified from within a function running through a process in Python.
Below is an example of how it behaves.

In a python shell I define a function:

Code:

```
>>> def myfct2(n):

...   for i in range(len(n)):

...    n[i] = i

...    time.sleep(3)
```

Then execute it with a 'None' list:

Code:

```
N=[None]*4

>>> N

[None, None, None, None]

>>> myfct(N)

>>> N

[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

The list gets change because it's mutable.

Now, if I do the same thing in a process it behaves differently:

Code:

```
proc=multiprocessing.Process( target=myfct,args=(N,),daemon=True)

 

N=[None]*4

 

>>> proc.start()

>>> proc.is_alive()

True

>>> proc.is_alive()

True

>>> proc.is_alive()

True

>>> proc.is_alive()

True

>>> proc.is_alive()

True

>>> proc.is_alive()

False

>>> N

[None, None, None, None]
```

Can someone tell me how can I modify a mutable object passed to a function argument through a process ?

Comment: `multiprocessing` *copies* data across processes. I am not sure whether this is an  appropriate [duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264699/shared-state-in-python-multiprocessing-processes). There are many questions about sharing state between processes that would probably make better duplicate targets. You should also [read the docs about shared state](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `proc.join()`. The above code worked for me in python 3. [Join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) makes the main process wait for the process you created before finishing. So maybe the script is done before the calculation in your function finishes.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def myfct2(n):

    for i in range(len(n)):
        n[i] = i
        time.sleep(3)

    print(n)

N=[None]*4
proc=multiprocessing.Process( target=myfct2,args=(N,))
proc.start()
proc.join()
```

Comment: Thanks, it's actually in a context of a gtk3 progress bar where I modify the value in a process. It's seem multiprocessing is not what I have to use here.