# Why python uses 'CallByValue' function call when a dict (mutable dtype) is an argument to a function that is implemented via multiprocessing Pool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, pool

Note: This is an contrived example to a bigger problem

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

dict1 = {'key1':1}

def alterDict(dict_num):
    for key in dict_num:
        dict_num[key] = 20000

alterDict(dict1)
print(dict1) # output is {'key1': 20000}



dict1 = {'key1':1}


with Pool(2) as p:
    p.map(alterDict,[dict1])

print(dict1) # output is {'key1': 1}
```

Why are the outputs different ? 
Is there a way to circumvent `Pool` from using a 'call by value' style of a function call ?
I want to make pool use a call by reference style of a function call

Comment: Multiple processes do not share state. This isn't really about the evaluation strategy of the function, multiprocessing hides a bunch of stuff, but it is actually creating separate python processes that execute those functions, and of course, in those processes the evaluation strategy is not call by value. As an aside, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shared state in multiprocessing Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264699/shared-state-in-multiprocessing-processes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are using  `multiprocessing` and you want to change object like `dict`, `list` etc.. (shared data)  you need to use [Sharing state between process](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def alterDict(dict_num): 
    for key, _ in dict_num.items(): 
        dict_num[key] = 20000 

with mp.Manager() as manager: 
    d = manager.dict() 
    d['key'] = 1 
    with manager.Pool() as pool: 
        pool.map(alterDict, [d]) 
    print(dict(d)) 

# {'key': 20000} # output
```

BTW you should use  `dict_num.items()` with `items` otherwise you will got error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py in _callmethod(self, methodname, args, kwds)
    848             dispatch(conn, None, 'decref', (token.id,))
    849             return proxy
--> 850         raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
    851 
    852     def _getvalue(self):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_registry'
```

Comment: thank you Beny Gj! Importing manager from multiprocessing solved the issue.