# How to check if two references to multiprocessing Queue objects point to the same memory location?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, producer-consumer

I'm writing a python software where a single producer process is generating data which has to be forwarded to multiple consumer processes. These consumers are not started and finished together. The main process starts various consumers based on external factors (such as connecting to a server, or the user actions on the GUI).

What I want to achieve is when a new consumer is created, a new `Queue` object is also added to the `MultiQueue` object, so that the producer start transfering data to the new consumer as well. When a consumer finishes (according to GUI or network events), it's queue should be removed from the `MultiQueue` object.

Here is a skeleton of what I have. I'm not really confident in multiprocessing yet, maybe my entire idea is bad practice, however it works as intended except for the `remove_queue()` method. How can I solve this issue?

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
from time import sleep

class MultiQueue():
    def __init__(self, queues = []):
        manager = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Manager()
        self.queues = manager.list()
        for queue in queues:
            self.add_queue(queue)

    def add_queue(self, queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
        """
        Add a queue
        """
        if not isinstance(queue, multiprocessing.managers.BaseProxy):
            raise ValueError("Input must be a multiprocessing.managers.Queue object")
        self.queues.append(queue)

    def remove_queue(self, queue):
        """
        Remove a queue by reference
        """
        if queue in self.queues:
            self.queues.remove(queue)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Queue not found in MultiQueue")

    def put(self, item, block=True, timeout=None):
        """
        Put an item into all queues
        """
        for q in self.queues:
            try:
                q.put(item, block=False)
            except multiprocessing.queues.Full:
                pass

    
class Producer(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queues: MultiQueue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queues = queues

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            self.queues.put(i)
            i+=1
            sleep(1)

def watcher(n, q):
    while True:
        i = q.get()
        print(f"[{n}]->{i}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Manager()
    q1 = manager.Queue()

    multiq = MultiQueue([q1])
    producer = Producer(multiq)
    proc.start()

    threading.Thread(target=watcher, args=(1, q1)).start() #consumer for q1

    sleep(3)
    
    q2 = manager.Queue()
    multiq.add_queue(q2)
    threading.Thread(target=watcher, args=(2, q2)).start() #consumer for q2

    sleep(3)
    
    multiq.remove_queue(q2) #the code runs correctly until this point
```

I know that queues don't implement the `__equal__` method, but is there a way to check if two of them in fact point to the same location?

Comment: In the shown code you can solve this by storing a dict instead of a list of the queues. The dict keys are the `id` numbers of the proxy objects, the values are the objects itself. Using this way you can find a proxy object by identity instead of equality. The `id` numbers are only unique in one process, not across multiple processes.

Comment: Not related to your specific question but I notice that your *put()* function would lose data if all queues are full

Comment: @MichaelButscher Sorry for the late reply, your answer does exactly what I wanted it to, thank you!

Comment: @DarkKnight It shouldn't really be a problem in this case, but thanks for pointing it out! I actually wanted to use deque-like objects instead of queues, so that if it's full, then the the oldest element is dropped and the new one is added instead. This could ensure that the gui for example has a 1s buffer for plotting the data, but if it slows down then it loses the older data in favor of the more recent. 

Sadly after doing some research, it seems like it's not doable in Python. There are some workarounds for similar results but all of them have drawbacks. I've chosen the simplest for now.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: *I have included an in depth explanation of what is exactly going wrong here, but if you're just here for the final solution, skip to the next section :)*

There is a fundamental misunderstanding here regarding what object you need to compare for equality. When you use a manager to create a queue (or any object for that matter), the actual object is created in a different server process, and what you get is a proxy object that can reference the real object in a different process.

The important thing to note here is that a single real object can have multiple proxy objects referencing it (that is, after all, the whole point: to provide synchronized access to a single object). However, the problem lies in the fact that these proxy objects can have different states with respect to each other, regardless of the actual state of the real object. This means that if the real object `R1` has two proxy objects, `P1` and `P2`, referencing it, then it is not guaranteed that they will pass the equality check (`P1 == P2` may be `False`) even though they both will provide access to the same state of the real object.

Putting it in simpler terms, when using proxies, equality checks may result in unexpected behaviour (your code would have worked if it wasn't using managers). To make sure that the equality checks behave as they normally would when using managers and proxies, we need to satisfy either of the two conditions:

1. Have `P1` and `P2` reference the same proxy, i.e., only work with
   and    create a single proxy object per real object. This would make
   sure    that all equality checks pass (since an object will always
   be equal    to itself)
2. Have a mechanism in place that compares the equality of the real object, rather than the proxy objects. Since both proxy objects point    to the same real object, this would mean that the equality checks    must pass too.

Having said all that, let's talk about your particular code. The relevant place where we can apply all this is in the line `if queue in self.queues` within the `remove_queues` method, where the equivalency check is implicit. Over here, it fails our condition (1) because we are comparing two different proxy objects. Why? Well, it's because we are using a managed list to store the managed queues which creates a problem for us because retrieving data (in this case, the data is our managed queues) from managed objects requires pickling and unpickling, creating duplicated versions of that data. Hence, iterating over the managed lists creates a new proxy for each managed queue within, failing our condition (1).

This also means that a potential fix is using a simple list to store the queues instead of a managed list. Of course, this comes with the drawback that simple lists cannot synchronize their state in case you pass the `MultipleQueue` objects to different processes. So what can we do? Use condition (2)

**Solution**

I won't go into too much detail, but the way this works is that we subclass `Queue` to include a unique identifier for each queue (using uuid4) during initialization. Then, we create a custom proxy with a `__eq__` method defined that uses this unique identifier to check whether the other proxy instance is pointing to the same real object as this one. Finally, we rebind these proxy and child class to the "Queue" typeid within the manager we create. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075761/16310741) for more details on making custom proxies in multiprocessing.

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
from time import sleep
from queue import Queue
import uuid
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseProxy, BaseManager, ListProxy, MakeProxyType, public_methods, NamespaceProxy


def make_proxy(name, cls, base=None):

    exposed = public_methods(cls) + ['__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__']
    return _MakeProxyType(name, exposed, base)


def _MakeProxyType(name, exposed, base=None):
    """
    Attempts to replicate multiprocessing.managers.MakeProxType properly
    """

    if base is None:
        base = NamespaceProxy
    exposed = tuple(exposed)

    dic = {}

    for meth in exposed:
        if hasattr(base, meth):
            continue
        exec('''def %s(self, *args, **kwds):
        return self._callmethod(%r, args, kwds)''' % (meth, meth), dic)

    ProxyType = type(name, (base,), dic)
    ProxyType._exposed_ = exposed
    return ProxyType


class MyManager(BaseManager): pass


class IdentityQueue(Queue):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._identity_uuid = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.get_identity()

    def get_identity(self):
        if not self._identity_uuid:
            self._identity_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        return self._identity_uuid


IdentityQueueBaseProxy = make_proxy("IdentityQueueBaseProxy", IdentityQueue)


class IdentityQueueProxy(IdentityQueueBaseProxy):
    """
    This is the custom proxy we are going to use, and the objects of this class will be the ones directly
    compared during equivalency checks in our code below.
    """
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, IdentityQueueProxy):
            if self.get_identity() == other.get_identity():
                return True
            return False

        raise NotImplemented


class MultiQueue():
    def __init__(self, queues=[]):
        ctx = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")
        manager = MyManager(ctx=ctx)
        manager.start()
        self.queues = manager.list()
        # self.queues = list()
        for queue in queues:
            self.add_queue(queue)

    def add_queue(self, queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
        """
        Add a queue
        """
        if not isinstance(queue, multiprocessing.managers.BaseProxy):
            raise ValueError("Input must be a multiprocessing.managers.Queue object")
        self.queues.append(queue)

    def remove_queue(self, queue):
        """
        Remove a queue by reference
        """

        if queue in self.queues:
            self.queues.remove(queue)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Queue not found in MultiQueue")

    def put(self, item, block=True, timeout=None):
        """
        Put an item into all queues
        """
        for q in self.queues:
            try:
                q.put(item, block=False)
            except multiprocessing.queues.Full:
                pass


class Producer(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queues: MultiQueue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queues = queues

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            self.queues.put(i)
            i += 1
            sleep(1)


def watcher(n, q):
    while True:
        i = q.get()
        print(f"[{n}]->{i}")

MyManager.register("Queue", IdentityQueue, IdentityQueueProxy)
MyManager.register('list', list, ListProxy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")
    manager = MyManager(ctx=ctx)
    manager.start()

    q1 = manager.Queue()
    multiq = MultiQueue([q1])
    print(q1==multiq.queues[0])  # True :)

    producer = Producer(multiq)
    producer.start()

    threading.Thread(target=watcher, args=(1, q1)).start()  # consumer for q1

    sleep(3)

    q2 = manager.Queue()
    multiq.add_queue(q2)
    threading.Thread(target=watcher, args=(2, q2)).start()  # consumer for q2

    sleep(3)

    multiq.remove_queue(q2)  # the code runs correctly until this point
```